# Write to Excel sheet using OpenXml c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml-sdk

I am trying to write to individual sheets in an `.xlxs` file. I have the following piece of code but it writes to all the sheets even if I am adding `sheetData` to a designated sheet.

```cs
private void WriteToSheet(string sheetName, string filePath)
{
    using var SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true);
    var wbPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
            
    if (wbPart == null)
        return;
            
    var sheets = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>();
    var sheet = sheets.SingleOrDefault((s) => s.Name.Equals(sheetName));
            
    if (sheet == null)
        return;
            
    var worksheet = ((WorksheetPart)wbPart?.GetPartById(sheet.Id)).Worksheet;
    var sheetData = worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());
            
    WriteTableHeader(sheetData);
    WriteTableData(sheetData);
    worksheet.Save();
}

private void WriteTableHeader(SheetData sheetData)
        {
            var row = sheetData.AppendChild(new Row());
            row.Height = 30;

            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("ID"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("File"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Entity"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Form"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Year"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Group"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Line"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Description"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Value 1"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Value 2"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Difference"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });
            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Order"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 8 });           
        }
```

Comment: What do you do inside the Write methods?

Comment: @riffnl - I am just adding rows to the sheetdata. One of the write method added above

Comment: This is one of the reasons I eventually went for the EPPlus nuget - saves you a lot of headaches..

Comment: This article helped solve the issue I was having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120544/openxml-multiple-sheets